# Sample dataframe by column with duplicate values in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, sample

Let's say I have 500 rows in a DF, which has 100 unique IDs. I want to sample 2% IDs in the DF, i.e, we want to keep 2% IDs and all the rows for that ID. How can we do that?

Comment: you would write a code that does that, if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to [use sample](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sampling-with-examples/#:%7E:text=Spark%20sampling%20is%20a%20mechanism,10%25%20of%20the%20original%20file.):

If you only want to Look at ID's then you may want to filter your dataset to the unique set of ID's first but this would give you the ability to randomly sample the data set:

> ```
> sample(fraction : scala.Double, seed : scala.Long) : Dataset[T]
> sample(fraction : scala.Double) : Dataset[T]
> sample(withReplacement : scala.Boolean, fraction : scala.Double, seed : scala.Long) : Dataset[T]
> sample(withReplacement : scala.Boolean, fraction : scala.Double) : Dataset[T]
> ```
>
> Scala Parameters
>
> fraction – Fraction of rows to generate, range [0.0, 1.0]. Note that
> it doesn’t guarantee to provide the exact number of the fraction of
> records.
>
> seed – Seed for sampling (default a random seed). Used to reproduce
> same random sampling
>
> withReplacement – Sample with replacement or not (default False).